# NUnit - Unable to find test in assembly

Tags: c#, nunit

I have added a test to a class library in Visual Studio 2010. However when I try to load the assembly in NUnit I get the following error:

Test load failed!

System.ApplicationException: Unable to find test in assembly.

What could be wrong? The test has the following simple code:

```
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Web.Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Test
    {
        [Test]
        public void ShouldLoadController()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(1,1);
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems commenting out the supportedRuntime version 'v2.0.50727' in the config file fixes this, but why can't it determine which runtime is in use?

Comment: Is the class Test part of the right assembly ? Did you load the correct assembly with NUnit ?

Comment: Yes, it is loading the correct assembly, it works if I set the runtime version as only 4.0 in the NUnit configuration. However if it is left as the default of 2.0 and 4.0, it produces this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be to comment out the reference to 2.0 in the Nunit configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <!-- Comment out the next line to force use of .NET 4.0 -->
    <!--<supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />-->
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

I'm not sure why this is necessary, as it appears that it should be able to select the correct run time.

Comment: I've accepted this answer as there didn't seem to be a better alternative.

Comment: I found this link and am too lazy to do more than post it here: https://www.howtosolutions.net/2013/04/solving-nunit-gui-test-load-failed-error-unable-to-find-test-in-assembly-visual-studio/

Comment: Also that file is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.2\bin or a similar path.