# NUnit - "Test load failed System.ApplicationException: Unable to find test in assembly"

Tags: nunit

I am using NUnit 2.6.3 and .NET framework 4.5.

I have a file, Test.NUnit, in my test project which contains:

```
<NUnitProject>
<Settings activeconfig="Debug"
         appbase="E:\Test" />
 <Config name="Debug" binpathtype="Auto">
   <assembly path="bin\Debug\Test.dll" />
 </Config>
 <Config name="Release" binpathtype="Auto" />
 </NUnitProject>
```

When I try to run this file I get an error message

> Test load failed System.ApplicationException: Unable to find test in assembly

The problem is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314614/nunit-unable-to-find-test-in-assembly). However, I can't get the answer to work.

I have a Test.dll.config file in my project which is located in E:\Test.

It contains:

```
 <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
      <!--<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />>-->
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" />
    </startup>
```

I have tried both versions of the supportedRuntime to show that I am using .NET framework 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Check your firewall blocking nunit-agent.exe trying to connect 127.0.0.1.

NUnit uses it for running tests and doesn't show the correct error if it can't connect to 127.0.0.1.